# Difference between Azure AD authentication, SQL Authentication, MSI & Token Library

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-synapse

I am beginner in Azure Synapse, could you please help me understand difference between Azure AD authentication, SQL Authentication, MSI & Token Library with respect to Synapse? In what scenario[Adhoc pipeline run, Scheduled job run etc.], these methods are used?

Answer (score 1):

**Azure AD Authentication**:

With Azure AD Authentication, you can centrally manage user identities that have access to Azure Synapse to simplify permission management.

Azure Active Directory enables you to have single place for user management

Azure AD supports Token Based Authentication for your Applications connecting to Azure Synapse

Azure AD helps stop the proliferation of user identities across servers

You can enable MFA and conditional access with Azure AD Authentication

Azure AD Authentication can be used if you need to provide access to Azure Synapse to a large group of users and manage them centrally

In Adhoc pipeline run, you can use Azure AD Authentication

**SQL Authentication**:

SQL Authentication can be used in case of legacy applications needs to use Synapse SQL in a well familiar way

In Scheduled Job run, you can use either SQL Authentication or Azure AD Authentication

**MSI Authentication**:

Managed Service Identity can be used if your resources in the Azure need to access the Azure Synapse Analytics

Using MSI, you do not need to provide additional credentials for your resources in the Azure to access Azure Synapse Analytics

**Token Library**:

Synapse uses Azure Active Directory (AAD) passthrough by default for authentication between resources.

If you need to connect to a resource using other credentials, use the TokenLibrary directly.

The TokenLibrary simplifies the process of retrieving SAS tokens, AAD tokens, connection strings, and secrets stored in a linked service or from an Azure Key Vault

**Reference**: [Azure Active Directory - Azure Synapse Analytics | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/sql/active-directory-authentication)

[Secure access credentials with Linked Services in Apache Spark for Azure Synapse Analytics - Azure Synapse Analytics | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/spark/apache-spark-secure-credentials-with-tokenlibrary?pivots=programming-language-csharp)

Comment: Thank you.. how is it different from MSI and Token Library ?